# Recover provisioning profile

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8

How do I recover a provisioning profile? I tested and released my app successfully with a profile A . Now, it seems to be gone and I cant recover it. Using my Git I was able to come back to the source code where profile A's ID is listed. It's a ~20 char code. It seems I can't locate the profile by the id in my developer.apple repository. My main problem now is that I can't test my app on my phone because xcode doesn't find a matching profile. I played with it a bit but now I am getting a

> CodeSign error: no provisioning profile at path '/Users/../Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/XYZ.mobileprovision

error when I try building for the phone?

Comment: Provisioning profile is stored in Apple Developer Portal. Click Refresh provisioning profiles in Xcode will sync the profiles with your computer.

Comment: Thanks, yes, but if I choose either one in my list I always get the now profile error... ? Clean before each try?

Comment: Check profile exist or not in /Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/.OR Download new profile from developer account and install it.

Comment: @abhijithpp hard to check, as the filenames are randomly generated.

Comment: @Raptor fine but you can delete all profiles in that folder and try reinstalling it.If its valid,you can see profile in code signing section.

Comment: Agree, Click Refresh provisioning profiles in Xcode will do the same